# How to filter a queryset in django model having a ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-admin, manytomanyfield

I have a "messages" model which has a **ManyToManyField** for "user".
In the admin site I can add a message for multiple users. I am trying to create a view which can filter the messages according to the user_id. Since a new table in the database is created for this ManyToManyField, how can I achieve the same

```
class Messages(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
message = models.CharField('Message',max_length=1000)
user = models.ManyToManyField('user',blank=True,null=True)
...
```

I want to do something like:

```
def sendMessage(userId)
    messageObj = Messages.objets.filter(user_id=userId)
```

Can anyone help me and tell **how I can filter the messages for a specific user**?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter the messages for a specific user, your code looks correct (it just has a typo). It should be something like this:

```
queryset = Messages.objects.filter(user=user)
```

If you want to use the `userID` (I would rename it to be `user_id`, personally):

```
queryset =  Messages.objects.filter(user.id=user_id)
```

Both of these will give you a `queryset`, which is an array like structure.You can continue to filter down if you need a more granular value. For example:

```
queryset.filter(message="this is my message").first() # this will now give you a single element
```

Comment: Thanks Bro @djq :)
I did 
`queryset =  Messages.objects.filter(user__id=user_id)`
and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set a [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for the relationship.

```
class Messages(models.Model):
...
user = models.ManyToManyField('user',blank=True,null=True, related_name='messages')
...
```

Then you can simply do `user.messages`, which returns a QuerySet with the user's messages